# Auto wrapping table columns when there is not enough space

Tags: html

I have to work with an old templating system to display shopping products on a web page. Today, all products are displayed one by row with all the details

```
P1
P2
P3
P4
```

This old software uses a pair of tags `<ED_START> <ED_END>` to mark the product template that must be repeated in the HTML page. In fact, each product has its own HTML table. It works up to day.

What now I want is to reduce display size by displaying elements horizontally and vertically, like

```
P1 P2
P3 P4
P5 P6
```

or

```
P1 P2 P3
P4 P5 P6
```

according to screen resolution.

I know that if I change the product template to be a `<td>`, then the browser will try to render 10 or more products on the same row, which is exactly what I don't want.

Normally, I would insert a `</tr><tr>` every 2 elements, but this templating system (this is a legacy proprietary software) doesn't allow that. The template must be the same for all items, pure HTML plus their own markers for price, description, picture, etc.

### My question is

How to I create in HTML a table that adapts the number of columns to available screen size (in other words, auto wrap columns as needed)? JavaScript and jQuery are usable.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [**responsive design**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) , [**twitter bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) is a good example of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with media queries - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5U7U/)

```
table {
    border: solid;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    table { width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 481px) {
    table { width: 49%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    table { width: 33%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good use of `div`s, like at http://android.hd2roms.com/, can help.

The secret is in the `float:left` style that makes them appear in sequence